# SQL Command not properly ended Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL query below says that it is not ended properly on the first Inner Join?If i remove the second table and the where clause the query is fine though?

```
SELECT homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft,
listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, home_type.type_name
FROM homes, bookings
WHERE bookings.booking_end < date '2013-01-23' OR bookings.booking_start > date '2013-01-22' AND bookings.home_id <> homes.home_id
INNER JOIN home_feature ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id 
INNER JOIN home_type ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code 
INNER JOIN features ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id 
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

Can anybody see any obvious errors with my query?

Comment: Do **not** mix implicit joins and explicit join syntax. Additionally the `JOIN` keywords goes *before* the `WHERE` clause. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2065646

Comment: You can't put a `where` there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is in the wrong place and you are mixing join types:

```
SELECT homes.home_id, 
    homes.title, homes.description, 
    homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, 
    homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, 
    homes.sqft,
    listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, 
    home_type.type_name
FROM homes
INNER JOIN bookings
    ON bookings.home_id = homes.home_id
INNER JOIN home_feature 
    ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id 
INNER JOIN home_type 
    ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code 
INNER JOIN features 
    ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id 
WHERE bookings.booking_end < date '2013-01-23' 
    OR booking_start > date '2013-01-22' 
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, 
       homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, 
       homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

The `WHERE` clause appears after the `JOIN` and before `GROUP BY`.  Also you should use one type of of join syntax. You were using both explicit and implicit syntax.  I moved the join of `homes` and `booking` to a `JOIN` instead of using a comma between the tables.